# Visual Studio intellisense not working in one .ascx file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I have two .ascx files in the same folder in an ASP.NET MVC project.

In one of them intellisense is working fine. In the other it does not work at all. Any ideas? The files are very similar with the same @control definition at the top.

Using VS2008 and C#.

Comment: Rebooting the machine worked but I'd still love to hear any other suggestions that anyone might have to solve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rebuilding your project.  Intellisense doesn't work in views until it has been built.

Comment: I had tried that - I did a clean and rebuild but no luck there.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I find deleting the designer.cs file, and then right clicking the .ascx and selecting 'Convert To Web Application' (which re-gens the desinger file) fixes weird intellisense errors.

Comment: Because I'm using ASP.NET MVC this control doesn't have a codebehind file and hence no designer file. Thanks anyway and +1 for a good tip.