# Visual Studio 2008 Intellisense missing

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense

Intellisense is suddenly missing from Visual Studio 2008 IDE on a project I am working. This was working fine. I rebooted the machine several times but still not working. It's working in other projects. What else could be causing this?

Comment: You also might want to have a look at these related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178846/visual-studio-intellisense-stopped-working, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371477/visual-studio-intellisense-not-working-in-one-ascx-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A third party dll was throwing an error in design mode. Only when I tried to open the form in Design View I noticed the error.

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting the .ncb files. Failing that, checkout a clean source tree.

Comment: Additionally follow other standard Visual Studio troubleshooting techniques: Restore the default settings and/or try the /SafeMode option.

Comment: I had the same problem but unfortunetly did doesn't worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Did you check under Tools/Options/Text Editor/(Your Language) to see if the auto complete is still on? There is "Auto List Members" under General and also Intelesense section has a show option.

Comment: I checked this earlier. The settings are perfect. It's just one particular project which was working fine until now.

Comment: That's strange. You might try creating a new solution for the project or even a new project and then add just your classes and config files to the new project.